# What are the new Nautilus (3.6) shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I post this question since new nautilus is very 'keyboard unfriendly', specially for one-key shortcuts. From 3.4 to 3.6 the very useful 'backspace' shortcut to go to parent directory has gone (along many other features).

In particular I would like to know how to go to the parent directory.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's not obvious looking at the user interface that there are any shortcuts. However most of the ones that worked in Nautilus 3.4.2 (as used in 12.04) still work in 3.6.

This list may not be exhaustive, feel free to edit this answer to add more if I have missed any out. All the following work in Nautilus 3.6 (as shipped with Ubuntu 13.04):

New tab <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

New window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

New folder <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Open folder in new tab <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>

Properties <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>

Close window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Close all windows (quit) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Make link <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Add bookmark <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Edit bookmarks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Undo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Redo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Select all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Select items matching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Invert selection <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Show hidden files <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Zoom in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Zoom out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

Normal size <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

List view <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Icons view <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

Go to home directory <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

Go to parent directory <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>

Go back <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

Go forward <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Go to specified location <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Search files (find) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Rename <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Should these be prominent in **Nautilus 3.6** desktop help content?

Comment: @david6 Should imho, but they are not there... only thing the help explains is Ctrl+S.

Comment: What is the source of this information ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Experience.  There used to be a list in Nautilus 3.4 but It got dropped for some reason.  I just tried all the ones I could remember to see which still worked.  I forgot a few but the beauty of the way this site works means that others have been able to fill in the ones I missed.

Comment: I was hoping to find the source, so may I can override some of these shortcuts. Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana : As the answer by drkokandy points out you can edit these shortcuts by editing `~/.config/nautilus/accels`  Make sure you take a backup first.

Comment: @WarrenHill, thanks. For v3.8.2 users (13.10), add this at the end of the file `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")`, without the `;` which seems to comment the line.

Answer (score 5):

In Nautilus 3.6, Alt + Up (Arrow) will take you to the parent directory.

If you are technically inclined, adding

```
gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace"
```

to the Nautilus config file (`~/.config/nautilus/accels`) will re-implement Backspace as the parent-directory shortcut. Source: http://devshards.blogspot.com/2013/04/edit-keyboard-shortcuts-in-nautilus-36.html

**Please backup your configuration file before trying to change it.** Inputting data wrong could probably break your nautilus.