# How do I type in a file path?

Tags: 13.10

How do I type in a file path in Ubuntu's default file explorer? By the looks of it, I can only drill down into folders by clicking on folder icons.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use this shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Or, go to **Files** and select **Enter Location**:

[image: Enter Location in Nautilus]

See also: [Where to configure shortcut keys of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69324/where-to-configure-shortcut-keys-of-nautilus)

Comment: As of 14.04 it is moved to **'Go'** menu and then **'Enter Location'**.

Comment: Would it reeeeeeaaaaaaaaally be too much to make this the default?

Comment: As of Ubuntu 17.10 there is no Files menu called "Enter Location" any more. But `Ctrl` + `L` is working very fine! (...and in the Files menu there is an option to display all keyboard shortcuts) Thx!!

Answer (score 6):

Another method that works is to just click on one of the tabs as if you were going to drill down and just start typing

The area immediately changes to a text box so you can enter a path.

As pointed out by Radu there is a short-cut key for this and you can also get there from the menu.  There is a useful list of short-cut keystrokes here:

[What are the new Nautilus (3.6) shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/293985/107450)

These work in both 13.04 and 13.10.

**Edit:**
In response to comment. Click one of the tabs you don't see any change but if you start typing you see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the first method or provide a screenshot?  I can't get the area to change to a text box by just clicking.

Comment: Why this answer is not the right one?  Because it is much faster than typing Сtrl-L shortcut and then typing the path.

Comment: Not sure whether this is version dependent, but when I just start typing it performs a search. Moreover the default is full text search (though I found a setting to search filenames only). As a result the GUI becomes unresponsive. So if I know the exact path, Ctrl-L better serves my needs.

Comment: @BorisMitioglov How is it faster two use _two_ input devices (mouse + keyboard) instead of only one (keyboard)? It takes approximately 0.15 seconds to press Ctrl+L but it takes at least 0.3 seconds to do it with the mouse and then switch to the keyboard...