# Inputting directory path via keybaord in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

In nautilus, if I paste in a full directory path into the top bar, nothing happens.

It seems that I can only search the path or select it via mouse based actions.

Is it possible to use the keyboard to edit the path in nautilus?

As an example, an action I'd like to do is when in a certain directory, going into a sibling directory -- which is as simple as changing the last fragment of location after "/".

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+L ? see for example [How do I type in a file path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366744/how-do-i-type-in-a-file-path)

Comment: That works. Thanks! Will vote to close my question as duplicate.