# Backspace shortcut for explorer

Tags: shortcut-keys, files, shortcuts

How can I access the folder that is used just before in "Files" using <kbd>Backspace</kbd> like which is done in Windows explorer??

Comment: Backspace also work in Ubuntu. Isn't? At least in Thunar it works.

Comment: @rainlover, I guess OP is asking b'coz it doesn't for him. OP kindly mention your Ubuntu build `(version)`. I too had the same problem in nautilus, coz pressing `Alt` + `Up Key` lead me back one directory. Idk the Ubuntu build i used though, Currently I am using Ubuntu 12.04, backspace key works fine in that.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to use <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but there are a few Keyboard shortcuts:

**<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> - Move 'Back' through history of navigated folders**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> - Move 'Forward' through history of navigated folders

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> - Move 'Up' - navigate to parent directory

There are more listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294004/178596)

---

You can change it to be the shortcut to navigate back, though it might be simpler to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

First kill nautilus with:

```
nautilus -q
```

*<sup>Note this will close any file manager windows, and probably anything it is doing</sup>*

Open the text editor with the file by running this in terminal or command prompt:

```
gedit ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

search for this line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then type `actions/Up`):

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "<Alt>Up")
```

and replace it with:
     (gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")

Save and exit, then close terminal, and open Files again, and it might work [image: smiley]

Comment: Exactly what i meant @wilf

Comment: Doesn't work at all...

Comment: Nautilus reverts the change back as soon as you try to use the combination, so your (gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace") becomes (gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "")

Comment: @jasmines - weird... thought it would work. I should really test my answers more often. No error messages occur which is also weird. If I knew where the system wide accels config file was *(if it even exists)*, i could suggest editing that....

Comment: @jasmines - it may be a Gnome/Unity or system thing to restrict keyboard shortcuts to certain parameters - Setting it to something like `<Primary>BackSpace` works. i also wonder if that relys on a config file.

Comment: Same with <Primary>Backspace. Nautilus reverts back to blank.

Comment: @jasmines - <Primary>Back**S**pace worked here...

Comment: Any idea how to make this work for `Space File Manager`?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this here:

1) Just add the accel key to the config file. I did in a terminal console:

`echo '(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")' >> ~/.config/nautilus/accels`

Restart nautilus after killing it by executing

`nautilus -q`

Or

2) edit `~/.config/nautilus/accels`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to find the right line.

Remove the `;` symbol in front of the line: `(gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "Up")`

Change <kbd>Up</kbd> to <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>

Hope it helps. :-) [image]

Comment: Do you want me to edit the last bit out my answer?

Comment: Ah, You too presented the solution. Nah, @wilf I suppose let it be there. Its okay, I don't mind. Have fun.

Comment: Doesn't work at all: Nautilus reverts the change back as soon as you try to use the combination, so your (gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace") becomes (gtk_accel_path "/ShellActions/Up" "")

Comment: @ASCIIbetical - that problem does seem to occur - anyway, where did you get that smiley :D