# How can I undo a recently closed tab in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

Most browsers have a 'undo closed tab' which will reopen a closed tab in case you closed it by mistake. For firefox, it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Can I replicate this behaviour in nautilus and how?

I looked at [nautilus shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293985/what-are-the-new-nautilus-3-6-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-13-04) but couldn't find a shortcut for that.

---

Assume you have a **deeply nested folder** thats open in a tab in nautilus, then as you go to select it, you accidentally close it. Now to reopen the tab, you will have to manually track it down under multiple other folders. Am looking for a shortcut (not necessarily keyboard) to restore the tab in the current open nautilus.

Comment: What version of ubuntu and nautilus are you using?

Comment: @Jobin Ubuntu 12.04, nautilus 3.4.2

Comment: I just want to be **really sure** that this feature doesn't exist.

Comment: So what is the Point on having this Functionallity - In my Opinion it is just for Human Comfort to reopen a Folder closed by Mistake. So my thinking goes on onto how do you open new Tabs (are you opening all Folders/Directorys in the same nautilus as tabs?) Or are you like me opening a main Folder and then just open Subfolders etc. via `Ctrl + Mouse Click`? If so - there is no need for this Feature doing a `Ctrl + Mouse Click` again will be faster than pressing a shortcut or are u using a 200" Flatscreen where you need to move your mouse over the whole Table to reach the other Monitor side ;)

Comment: @konqui The point is, assume you have a **deeply nested folder** thats open in a tab in nautilus, then as you go to select it, you accidentally close it. Now to reopen the tab, you will have to manually track it down under multiple other folders. Am looking for a shortcut (not necessarily keyboard) to restore the tab in the current open nautilus.

Comment: If im doing stuff deep inside neested folders i use the Console to travel through the Folders (has a nice plus auto expansion of folder names -> less tiping). So first travel there inside the Console and then open nautilus from there. So then if i accidentally close it i just can reopen it from console. `arrow up` and `Return` then im back. Also a nice plus of traveling inside the console - if i know i need to come back to the current folder i do open the next with pushd not cd. `pushd` and `popd` are builtin commands of the Console/Shell in Unix/Linux Systems and work like a Stack.

Comment: Only if nautilus supported plugins............. This shouldn't be difficult to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Nautilus or any of the major file browsers have this feature.

The only File manger I have seen this feature is [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/).

According to ranger website:

> ranger is a file manager with VI key bindings. It provides a minimalistic and nice curses interface with a view on the directory hierarchy.

In ranger you can use `uq` keybinding to undo closed tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Till now there is no shortcut for this behavior. You just can't open recently closed tab.

Please note that nautilus is a file browser and it's totally different from web browsers such as firefox and google chrome.

I don't think there exists a file browser with this feature to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: How come there is no file browser with this feature? It seems like a really basic feature.

Comment: I agree that its a nice option but that's the truth my friend